# Program task in ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, electron

I edit my question and my code to make it simpler. I need those two functions to be executed automatically every x time:

```
ipcMain.handle('get', () => {
   getProducts()
   getDatarticulo()
});
```

I have tried setInterval but it doesn't work, it doesn't run again, do you know why? Thank you.

```
ipcMain.handle('get', () => {
   getProducts()
   getDatarticulo()
   setInterval('getProducts()',1000)
   setInterval('getDatarticulo()',1000)
});
```

It gives me this error

Error occurred in handler for 'get': TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received 'getProducts()'

Comment: `but it does not work.` Means what? Of course your program needs do be opened to execute the code... Please clarify your problem.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering! Doesn't work means it doesn't do what I want it to do (I want that function to run by itself every 60 seconds)

Comment: Add some debugging points. Like a simple `console.log` or `debugger` breakpoints. Check if the interval is really executing every 60 seconds, and your function is called.

Comment: `setInterval(getProducts, 1000)` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 setInterval(()=>{
  getProducts();
},1000);
```

try use this